# Get CLSID from ProgID

Tags: c++, com, registry, clsid, progid

I am working on small program using com component on windows 10 1909, but I've got a problem with com function CLSIDFromProgID.
The c++ code is as follows.

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
HRESULT hr = NULL;
CLSID clsid;
LPOLESTR pProgID = L"ProvisioningWapDPURemote";
hr = ProgIDFromCLSID(clsid, &pProgID);
```

I checked out that the progid exists in registry, but whenver I execute this code, ProgIDFromCLSID function returns invalid class string. What's more, when I get progid from clsid, the clsid I got is same as original one, I mean "ProvisioningWapDPURemote". I cannot find what the problem is. Could anyone help me?

Comment: ProgIDFromCLSID "retrieves the ProgID for a given CLSID". not reversed

Comment: You must be looking for CLSIDFromProgID instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-clsidfromprogid

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentions `CLSIDFromProgID()`, but your code is calling `ProgIDFromCLSID()` instead.  You need to call the former, eg:

```cpp
CLSID clsid;
LPOLESTR pProgID = L"ProvisioningWapDPURemote";
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(pProgID, &clsid);
```